Set Meld as external diff tool in gitk - permissions error MacOS
I am trying to setup Meld as an external diff tool in gitk on macOS however I stumbled on an error when trying to open a diff.
/ Applications/Meld.app: command
failed: couldn't execute "/
Applications /Meld.app": permission denied

What I have tried is:

to add gitk (installed via brew) to the Privacy & Security -> Application & Developer settings;
elevating permissions with:  chmod -R 755 chmod -R 755 /opt/homebrew/bin/gitk
Re-sign the application with: codesign --force --deep --sign - /opt/homebrew/bin/gitk

I have previously used Meld as an external diff tool with MacOS, but unfortunately do not remember what was the procedure.

What are the permissions of the Meld.app in the Application Folder?

@WolfgangWilke drwxr-xr-x
I guess that the issue is with gitk as it is trying to open a different application. But that is just a guess.
